# Serving static files from Express without extension, issue with sub directories with same name a file

Tags: node.js, express

The goal here is to serve my static site (generated with nuxtjs) with url without trailing slash.

I want to serve `foo.html` with url `/foo`
To do that I am using express static with extensions option

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public', { extensions: 'html' }))
```

That is working fine **except when an html file has the same name as a folder**.
Let's consider this file tree :

```
foo.html
bar.html
bar/baz.html
```

`/foo` will serve `foo.html`

`/bar/baz` will serve `baz.html`

but `/bar` will redirect to `/bar/`

I tried to deactivate the redirect option that way :

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public', { extensions: 'html', redirect: false }))
```

Now `/bar` is not redirecting anymore but the file `bar.html` is still not served !

Express is just moving to next()

I was able to serve bar.html adding this after other routing :

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var file = __dirname + '/public' + req.path + '.html'
    fs.exists(file, function(exists) {
        if (exists) res.sendFile(file)
        else next()
    })
})
```

But I feel this should not be the right way to do that, I should be able to serve all my files with static.

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you're trying to do, but when `express.static()` finds that `/foo` matches a `foo` directory in the static file hierarchy, it then looks inside that directory for an `index.html` file and, if found, it will serve that.  Perhaps you can use that to solve your issue.

Comment: Well to be exact when : `express.static()` finds that `/foo` matches a `foo` directory in the static file hierarchy it will redirect to `/foo/`, and then `/foo/` request will be served with `/foo/index.html` but because of that redirect url will be `/foo/` with the trailing slash. 
The thing is my site generated with nuxt js that work as a single page app has visible href without trailing slashes therefore it will look like all my links are pointing to 301 redirects. And my boss believe it's bad (because his SEOs tools will show some red).

Comment: How many of these directory URLs do you have?  You could just define manual routes for them that do exactly what you want.

Comment: so there is no express solution for this? is there?

Comment: looks like an open issue on express: https://github.com/expressjs/serve-static/issues/138

Answer (score 0):

From Express 4.8.0, you can use [res.sendFile](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.sendFile) as an alternative to express.static. It uses the same backing code, and supports the same features such as HTTP cache support, content-type headers, etc.

```
const root = path.join(__dirname, '/public');
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  const file = req.url + ".html";
  fs.exists(path.join(root, file), (exists) =>
    exists ? res.sendFile(file, {root}) : next()
  );
});
```